# Testing for Concurrent users for a dynamic web appliacation

Tags: java, jsp, testing

I would like to test a web application which takes an input as parameter and produces output. I don't want to do load or stress testing, I would like to have some 100 users inputting the parameter and clicking the submit. How can we automate this?

The web application I would like to test is http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/MongoTest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve such functionality by using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.

The way to do this is something like the following:

```
//set browser
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10); 
//not to throw exception on javascript error
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
//set page to access
final HtmlPage homepageEn = webClient.getPage("http://protein.rnet.missouri.edu:8080/MongoTest/");
//get the form by id
HtmlForm form = homepageEn.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='input_form']"); 
//setup the fields to use 
HtmlTextInput mailField = form.getInputByName("mail");
HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = form.getInputByName("password");
//define the submit button (defined by value)
HtmlSubmitInput submitButton = form.getInputByValue("submit");
//change the value of text fields
mailField.setValueAttribute("somemail@xyzmail.com");
passwordField.setValueAttribute("some_password");
//finally submit the form by clicking the button
final HtmlPage resultsPage = submitButton.click();
```

You can then implement the 100 users maybe using a loop or something. That's totally up to you..

Hope this helps...